# i am unable to execute the sample_app gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

> There was an error parsing Gemfile:
>   syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '(' - ...m 'database_cleaner', git clone 'git://github.com/maccman/gd...
>   ...                               ^
>   /home/phorekka/rails_project/sample_app/Gemfile:28: syntax error, unexpected unary-, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
>   ...an/gdata.git' "foobar" --bare --no-hardlinks
>   ...                               ^. Bundler cannot continue.

#  from /home/phorekka/rails_project/sample_app/Gemfile:28
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #    gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false >
    gem 'database_cleaner', git clone 'git://github.com/maccman/gdata.git' "foobar" --bare --no-hardlinks

```html
   > Here is my gem file.
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.8'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.1.2'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.8'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', '4.0.0'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.35.1'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.0'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  #gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
   gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
  # gem 'wdm', '0.1.0'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '3.0.4'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

> I am using sqlite3 --version
>   3.8.11.1 2015-07-29 20:00:57 cf538e2783e468bbc25e7cb2a9ee64d3e0e80b2f.
>    I am not able to run this gemfile. Help me please.

Comment: are you following Micheal Hartl's tutorial?

Comment: Yes I am! @Nirupa. Can you please help me out?

Comment: Okay first which chapter are you talking about? And please post your github link to this.

Comment: @Nirupa.. This is chapter 3 (Mostly static Pages,Sample_app). I was trying to run bundle for  test driven environment . After running bundle command , I had the above error. Should i elaborate the problem??  Here is my github link for the repository called "Sample_app". [https://github.com/phorekka/Sample_app]

Comment: Just send me github link

Comment: Here is the link , [ https://github.com/phorekka/Sample_app.git ]

Comment: Now the link is working.. @Nirupa

Comment: I'll update you in a while

Comment: please see the answer and let me know if this helped you or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Gemfile is different than the one in third chapter,

I just replaced your Gemfile with the one in book:
[image]

And then executed `bundle install --without production` and it works fine.

Also run `bundle update` after that and you'll be good to go.

Try it yourself and let me know if you have other question.

Comment: It is recommended that you follow the book step by step and try to understand what the author is trying to explain